# Swift iOS In table view Can I use reloadData after adding a row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In table view
If use reloadData after adding a row, I think perfomence is not good
Is reloadData designed for that?

if not 
How do I add a row?

FirstTime i Used `reloadData()`
now Used

```
 let index = IndexPath(row: dataList.count - 1, section: 0)
 tableView.storyTableView.insertRows(at: [index], with: .none)
```

but raise `NSInternalInconsistencyException`

So i will use reloadData again

Is there any problem if I keep using reloadData?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if dataList.count < 1{
        self.emptyTableLabel.layer.zPosition = 2
    }else{
        self.emptyTableLabel.alpha = 0
    }
    return dataList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DataCell", for: indexPath) as! Datacell
    cell.parentTable = self
    let data = self.dataList[indexPath.row]
    cell.indexLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row+1)"
    cell.nick.text = (data["UserNick"] as! String)
    cell.content.text = (data["Content"] as! String)
    cell.index = indexPath.row
    cell.time.text = (data["RegisterDate"] as! String).calculDateTime()
    return cell
}
```

Dynamically adds values ​​from the user to the table view,
It works well when data comes in one by one.

But An NSInternalInconsistencyException is thrown if multiple values ​​are received almost simultaneously.

Comment: 1. Show more relevant code. Where do you update the data model before calling `insertRows`? If you don't that's the cause of the error. 2. No need to call `beginUpdates/endUpdates` for a single call to `insertRows`. 3. Don't needlessly call `reloadData`. Fix your issue instead.

Comment: @rmaddy Dynamically adds values ​​from the user to the table view.
An NSInternalInconsistencyException is thrown if multiple values ​​are received almost simultaneously.

Comment: We can call reload data. no problem can you show the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath , numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: performBatchUpdates(<#T##updates: (() -> Void)?##(() -> Void)?##() -> Void#>, completion: <#T##((Bool) -> Void)?##((Bool) -> Void)?##(Bool) -> Void#>)

Comment: @Ruban4Axis Add More Info In post

Comment: After insertion where you are updating dataList array. I think when reloading there is problem

Answer (score 1):

[Go through this Perform updates method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618045-performbatchupdates) .

```
func performBatchUpdates(_ updates: (() -> Void)?, 
              completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

Perform the insertion here and Reload the Tableview after Completion

Answer (score 1):

```
tableView.performBatchUpdates ({
    let index = IndexPath(row: dataList.count - 1, section: 0)
    tableView.storyTableView.insertRows(at: [index], with: .none)
},
completion: { (success) in
    tableView.reloadData()
}
)
```

Check this one